# How to send popup alert to my apple IOS users?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

I have one app online into my itunesconnect account and recently I have created a new app of the same service. 
I started a new one because it was less time spending started a new app from scratch. Now I want to notify to the users of my older app that there is a new app that is the upgraded of the older one.

There is any way to send a popup through itunes connect because I'm the owner of both?

thanks for any kind of suggestion

Comment: Just update your app's build on itunesconnect with your new one using same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Push notification should be your answer or you can implement an alert for old app that can be triggered later via an endpoint or push notification as well.